# Blanking/changing Mac OS X password in Linux

Tags: linux, macos, password-recovery

I have a computer running Mac OS X, and I have a Linux [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) (I have Ubuntu 11.04, 10.4, and [BackTrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BackTrack) 5). How do I blank the password on Mac OS X from my start CD, what program is necessary, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in [single user mode](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080414140636495) without a Linux live CD or an installer DVD.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ten years ago, we had lower standards- and a link only answer was a terrible idea. On the other hand - frankly doing it from linux made no sense, and doing it natively was the right thing to do. 12 years on though, I don't really remember much about the answer, nor OS X and I'll look at trying to fix this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use your OSX DVD if available. Why do you need to use Linux?

Comment: Agreed, this is very straightforward to do from the OSX installer.

Comment: It is not that i <i>need</i> to do it from linux, its that i would like to know how.